# How can I implement this animated theme into my background of the webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to implement the codepen linked below into my `intro-section` background. I'm trying to get the dotted animated theme behind the `<p>` text on my `intro-section` background.

[**JSFIDDLE - My attempt**](https://jsfiddle.net/ntxLtzs2/)

[**JSFIDDLE link I'm trying to implement into my `intro-section` background**](https://codepen.io/html5andblog/pen/jWbLbj)

Comment: Welcome @Jon Bridge:  Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve, and what you are showing in the links you provide?

Comment: I'm trying to get the dotted animated theme behind the text animation on the first section of my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the console log, you'll notice that you have a script error which is caused on line 48 when you are trying to run the following block of code:

```
var canvas = oCanvas.create({
   canvas: '#canvas',
   background: '#2c3e50',
   fps: 60
});
```

This is caused because you have not included the [Ocanvas](http://ocanvas.org/) library in your fiddle but you are trying to create an OCanvas object.

You can reference external resources like the Ocanvas library from the "External Resources" section in jsfiddle

In order to place the canvas below the welcome text you can position that section absolutely. I have defined a new css class as `.header-container` to achieve that and adjusted the padding of the `.intro-section`

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ntxLtzs2/3/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! Would it be possible to  implement the dotted circles animated theme  behind the `<p>` text on my `intro-section` background so it fills the whole of the `intro-section`

Comment: You can move the text down so it's centered within the `intro-section`:  https://jsfiddle.net/ejm6g7b3/